# Cross-User Tesing React / Redux Application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm looking for the simplest and most effective way to perform cross-user testing (not automated) with simulatneously logged-in mock accounts in a React / Redux application with React and Redux devtools enabled.

Logging in with separate Chrome Incognito windows for each account fails to propagate data to devtools (permissions are enabled to access in Incognito and allow Url access).

Also, how is this situation typically approached in major production environments?

Comment: Solved by simply running another instance of my dev server on another port. Still curious how others would approach this